# Arabic Locale Support in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, locale, arabic

Today, I learn how to localize my Flex application and to support multiple languages. The tutorials on-line are great. However, non of them mention the Arabic locale.

So basically, I created the Arabic (Jordan) locale files in the SDK folder by using:

```
copylocale en_US ar_JO
```

I navigated to the locale folder and I was able to see the `ar_JO` folder in there... So I assume everything went smooth.

Next, I followed the tutorials ([www.babelfx.org](http://www.babelfx.org/)) and was able to localize my test application in English, French, and Arabic. Clicking on any of those languages switches the labels of my simple form/into the desired language... however:

1. When switching to the Arabic language the labels turn into empty square symbols. If you are wondering, yes I can open a notepad and type Arabic text and save it successfully.
2. When I type Arabic text into the text boxes, I can see the Arabic words that I typed correctly (the labels are still square symbols).

Any ideas what I might be missing here??

I tried changing the font of my application (right on the application tag I set the `fontFamily`) into `Simplified Arabic` which comes by default on Windows.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. Actually, I didn't have to embed any fonts or anything in order to get it working.

My problem was the encoding in the `resources.properties` file. I opened it in Notepad++, then I noticed the `Encoding` menu. At that time, I remembered reading something about that the encoding of the resources files should be `UTF-8`. So I converted the encoding to `UTF-8` from the menu, compiled, it didn't work! After couple of retries and cleaning the project, it worked successfully!!!

Just a reminder for everybody (as I have fallen into this while working this problem out):
For `mx` components, embedded fonts must have the `embedAsCFF` set to `false`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you embedded a font into your `swf` which can render Arabic? Are you using that font? If the answer is no to either, then I suggest [reading up on the subject](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7f5f.html).

One thing to remember about Flash and fonts is that it has incredible power which comes from the fact that one is able to embed actual fonts into the swf itself. One also needs to remember that Flash is incredibly finicky and is prone to throwing fits if you fail to do so.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.

I followed your suggestion and embedded fonts into my application. The letters show as blank square symbols.

Comment: I tried something else. I opened the resources.properties from within the Flash Builder IDE... and I the letters show as different symbols. I manually edited one of those values, I was able to type in arabic. When I saved the properties file, it didn't work and it said:

"Save could not be completed.
Reason:
Some characters cannot be mapped using "ISO-88591-1" character encoding. Either change the encoding or remove the characters which are not supported by the "ISO-8859-1" character encoding".

not sure if this is related

Comment: actually I found the solution... read the edited part in my question. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to change the context-type to UTF-8.  Three ways to accomplish this from within Flex Builder:

  (Option 1) Right click the file from the File Navigator and select Properties
  (Option 2) With the file open, navigate to the File menu and choose Properties
  (Option 3) With the file open, press Alt + Enter to bring up the file Properties

Once the properties window is displayed, you will see the option to change the file encoding from **Default** to **Other** (UTF-8).

**Note:** At least for me, once I changed the content-type to UTF-8, I had to close my unsaved file, open it back up, and paste my contents back into the file in order to clear the error message.  Then **clean** the project (Project -> Clean...) and let it rebuild.