# Flex 3 - Right to Left text

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3, arabic, right-to-left

I have a "Flex Application" that uses flex builder 3,

I want to add Arabic translation to this application,  and for this purpose I need to change the flow of all the labels, button-text, tree nodes-text and etc. - to "Right to Left" direction, (I need also to change the components' flow to "Right to Left" direction, but let start with the text itself....),

So, how can I do it without moving to Flex 4?

Answer (score 0):

Basically you are looking for "Arabic" localization support for your flex app. Following thread already discussed the similar question:

[Arabic Locale Support in Flex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7692092/arabic-locale-support-in-flex)

Comment: This is not my problem, I succeeded to see Arabic letters just the words order is reversed.